# Dealing with NA values when using aggregate in R

Tags: r, function, aggregate, na

I am trying to calculate daily maximum data when the dataset has `NA` values. Without specifying `na.action` or `na.rm`, this is the error message I get:

> Warning message: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : no non-missing arguments to
> max; returning -Inf

To fix this, I've tried this:

```
df_dailymax <- aggregate(df$col2, by = list(df$date), FUN=function(x) max(x, na.rm=TRUE))
```

But then I get the error message:

> Error in lapply(X = unname(split(e, grp)), FUN = FUN, ...) : invalid
> formal argument list for "function"

Is there a way to include `NA` values in the data without returning `-Inf`? Thank you!

Comment: `max(x, na.rm = !all(is.na(x)))` untested

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).